# Derive sequence formula directly from partial sum formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Suppose we have a partial sum formula for the sequence $a_n$ :

$ S_n =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k $.

Is there any way to derive sequence formula $ a_n $ directly from
$S_n$?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  $a_n=S_n-S_{n-1}$, for example.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Do you mean a "closed formula" ? This is not possible in general.